# A question about a little gusess the age game i made with Js

Tags: javascript

in my udemy course, we just got introduced to JS! 
I love this language, and right now I'm pretty much a novice. 
I hope you can help me, i want my code to keep asking the user to guess the age that I've set as the sercretNumber.

i got 2 problems :

1) I think my code can and need to be shorter maybe with some OR and AND.

2) I can't get it to tell the user that if the number is negative or above 100, to prompt the user again for input by saying - Your number needs to be from 1-100.
 I get it to work once and it's gone!

here's the Js code :

```
var secretNumber=98;
var numbGues=Number(prompt("Can you guses My age? (Hint - its 1-100"))




    while (numbGues!=secretNumber){

    // here I want this message to keep repeating if the user enters a non-valid input such as: -987 , or 54564654//

      if (numbGues<0 || numbGues>100 ){
        var numbGues=Number(prompt("Pleae choose a valid number between 1-100"))
      }



      if (numbGues<secretNumber){
        var numbGues=Number(prompt("Too low! try again"))
      }



     else  if (numbGues>secretNumber) {
        var numbGues=Number(prompt("Too High! Try again!"))
      }

      if (numbGues==secretNumber) {
        alert("You guessed it!")
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about the if, if - else if, if structure you have here. It's possible to streamline it. Once you've covered all bases, you don't need another if, you just need an else to end the conditional statement.

As to your second point, in your first if statement, you're already prompting the user for the very same situation you mentioned. Just replace it with the error message you want to be displayed in that block.

Answer (score 0):

little bit changed your code. you need to change

```
  if (numbGues==secretNumber) {
    alert("You guessed it!")
  }
```

this if statement. finally your code looks like this.

```
var secretNumber=98;
var numbGues=Number(prompt("Can you guses My age? (Hint - its 1-100"));
while (numbGues!=secretNumber){
// changed if else statements
  if (numbGues<0 || numbGues>100 ){
    numbGues=Number(prompt("Pleae choose a valid number between 1-100"));
  }else if (numbGues<secretNumber){
    numbGues=Number(prompt("Too low! try again"));
  }else  if (numbGues>secretNumber) {
    var numbGues=Number(prompt("Too High! Try again!"));
  }
}
//you need to check this if statement in here otherwise if user entered secret number first time didn't show any alert
if (numbGues==secretNumber) {
    alert("You guessed it!")
}
```